# Convert NSString to NSUTF32StringEncoding

Tags: ios, unicode, nsstring, emoji, utf-32

I have an NSString that internally uses UTF16 encoding. I want to covert it to use UTF32 , so that 
 `or q` both take single index. Currenty  takes 2.

How to do this ?. Even if I can convert to some other type from NSString it will work. Bottom line is to have  `or q` take equal number of indexes in an array.

Comment: "" is one character. Both "" and "q" take one "index" in an `NSArray`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try :

```
NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding];

NSString *convertedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `[[NSString alloc]initWithData:encoding:]`?

Example would be:

```
NSData *data = [sourceStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
```

Create your `NSUTF32StringEncoded` string from the data above

```
NSString *encodedStr = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding];
```